# Is it possible to create some IGrouping object

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have `List<IGrouping<string,string>>`.

Is is somehow possible to add new item to this list? Or actually, is it possible to create some IGrouping object?

Comment: The answers below show you how you could do this, but you probably want to considering implementing a `Dictionary`, `Lookup` or other structure more suited to your purpose.  .NET has plenty of great classes to help with structuring your data and I'm confident that something already exists that will meet your needs.

Comment: As this caused a lot of questions why I do this, here it is: I queried to get result and stored it, and I knew that source has changed and I believed that it was less costly to add new element manually than to query again.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you really wanted to create your own `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`, it is a simple interface to implement:

```
public class Grouping<TKey, TElement> : List<TElement>, IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    public Grouping(TKey key) : base() => Key = key;
    public Grouping(TKey key, int capacity) : base(capacity) => Key = key;
    public Grouping(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> collection)
        : base(collection) => Key = key;
    public TKey Key { get; }
}
```

> **Note**: you shouldn't try to allow the `Key` to be settable, mainly because the key should be managed by the collection that this Grouping is contained within.

This class inherits from `List<T>` and implements the `IGrouping` interface. Aside of the requirement of being an `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<TElement>` (which `List<T>` satisfies) the only property to implement is `Key`.

You could create `List` of these groups from scratch:

```
var groups = new List<Grouping<string, string>>();
groups.Add(new Grouping<string,string>("a", new string [] { "apple" }));
groups.Add(new Grouping<string,string>("p", new string [] { "peach", "pear" }));
groups.Add(new Grouping<string,string>("o", new string [] { "orange" }));

// inline variant:
groups = new List<Grouping<string, string>>
{
    new Grouping<string, string>("a", new string[] { "apple" }),
    new Grouping<string, string>("p", new string[] { "peach", "pear" }),
    new Grouping<string, string>("o", new string[] { "orange" }),
};
```

Or you could use this structure to append new groups to the results of a previous *Linq* `GroupBy` expression that has been evaluated into a list:

```
var strings = new string [] { "apple", "peach", "pear" };
var groups = strings.GroupBy(x => x.First().ToString()).ToList();
…
// Inject a new item to the list, without having to re-query
groups.Add(new Grouping<string,string>("o", new string [] { "orange" }));
```

If you need to add Items to the groups resolved from an IGrouping expression you can cast the Linq results into a `List` of `Grouping`:

```
var strings = new string [] { "apple", "peach", "orange" };
var groupExpression = strings.GroupBy(x => x.First().ToString());
var editableGroups = groupExpression.Select(x => new Grouping<string,string>(x.Key, x)).ToList();
…
// Add "pear" to the "p" list, with a check that the group exits first.
var pGroup = editableGroups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "p");
if (pGroup == null)
    editableGroups.Add(new Grouping<string, string>("p", new string[] { "pear" }));
else
    pGroup.Add("pear");
```

Comment: So when I instantiate this, I can obviosly set the key, but how do I set the items?

Comment: Since `MyGrouping<TKey, TElement>` inherits from `List<T>`, it has all the properties and methods of that class.  See it's documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Comment: Sorry I meant to post a follow up comment.  I used AddRange() to dump in an existing list.

Comment: Probably the easiest approach would be something like: var newGrouping = new List<MyType>().GroupBy(t => t.MyKey);

Comment: Enhanced version: 
'
    public class Grouping<TKey, TSource> : List<TSource>, IGrouping<TKey, TSource>
    {
        public Grouping(TKey key) : base() => Key = key;
        public Grouping(int capacity, TKey key) : base(capacity) => Key = key;
        public Grouping(IEnumerable<TSource> collection, TKey key) : base(collection) => Key = key;
        public TKey Key { get; private set; }
    }'

Comment: Not all groups of data can easily or efficiently be formed from a single Linq statement, this solution allows us to build grouping manually, but still use the results in CollectionViewSource for Xaml collection controls.

Answer (score 15):

As of .NET 4.0, there do not appear to be any *public* types in the BCL that implement the `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` interface, so you won't be able to 'new one up' with any ease.

Of course, there's nothing stopping you from:

1. Creating a concrete type yourself that implements the interface, as @Nathan Anderson points out.
2. Getting an instance / instances of `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` from a LINQ query such as `ToLookup` and `GroupBy` and adding it / them to your list.
3. Calling `ToList()` on an existing sequence of groups (from ToLookup / GroupBy).

Example:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = ..
var barsByFoo = foos.ToLookup(foo => foo.GetBar());

var listOfGroups = new List<IGrouping<Foo, Bar>>();

listOfGroups.Add(barsByFoo.First()); // a single group
listOfGroups.AddRange(barsByFoo.Take(3)); // multiple groups
```

It's not clear *why* you would want to do this, though.

Answer (score 10):

```
IGrouping<TKey, TElement> CreateGroup<TKey, TElement>(IEnumerable<TElement> theSeqenceToGroup, TKey valueForKey)
{
    return theSeqenceToGroup.GroupBy(stg => valueForKey).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Excelent and simple solution

Comment: Short, but a lot of overhead for something that should be simple.

Comment: If the source sequence is empty, this returns null instead of an empty group.

Answer (score 7):

You can also hack the grouping by not grouping on something within the list:

```
var listOfGroups = new[] { "a1", "a2", "b1" }
                       .GroupBy(x => x.Substring(0, 1))
                       .ToList();

// baz is not anything to do with foo or bar yet we group on it
var newGroup = new[] { "foo", "bar" }.GroupBy(x => "baz").Single();

listOfGroups.Add(newGroup);
```

`listOfGroups` then contains:

```
a:
    a1, a2
b:
    b1
baz:
    foo, bar
```

[IDEOne example](https://ideone.com/kntNIO)

Answer (score 3):

Based on dovid's answer, I created the following extension method, that creates an instance of `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` from an `IEnumerable<TElement>` and a key of type `TKey`:

```cs
public static IGrouping<TKey, TElement> ToGroup<TKey, TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TElement> elements,
    TKey keyValue)
{
    return elements.GroupBy(_ => keyValue).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

It can be called like this:

```cs
var fruits = new [] { "Apples", "Bananas" };
var myFruitsGroup = fruits.ToGroup("fruitsKey");
```

Beware that `ToGroup()` can return `null`.

I also created an additional `GroupBy` extension method:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TElement>> elementsSelector)
{
    return source
        .Select(s => elementsSelector(s)
            .ToGroup(keySelector(s)))
        .Where(g => g != default(IGrouping<TKey, TElement>));
}
```

It can be used like this:

```cs
var foodItems = new []
{
    new { Category = "Fruits", Items = new [] { "Apples", "Bananas" } },
    new { Category = "Vegetables", Items = new [] { "Tomatoes", "Broccoli" } },
};
var categoryGroups = foodItems.GroupBy(i => i.Category, i => i.Items);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var headers = from header in new[] {
  new { Name = "One", List = new[] { "One 1", "One 2", "One 2" } },
  new { Name = "Two", List = new[] { "Two 1", "Two 2", "Two 2" } }
} from value in header.List group value by header.Name;
```

Answer (score -4):

The `IGrouping` interface is for the `GroupBy()` operator in LINQ. You would normally get an `IGrouping` object from a LINQ query with a *`group by`* clause. It doesn't make much sense to have a list of groupings, though.

Comment: Well, given that the return type of GroupBy is `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>` is actually makes a lot of sense to have a list of groupings, considering that List is just one of the many ways to have an `IEnumerable`.