# What is the implementing class for IGrouping?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-data-services

I am trying create a WCF Data Services ServiceOperation that does grouping on the server side and then sends the data down to the client.

When I try to call it (or even connect to the service) I get an error.  It says that it can't construct an interface.

The only interface I am using is IGrouping.

What is a/the actual class for this interface?

---

**Update:**

I checked the type while debugging a sample app and it told me it was:

```
System.Linq.Lookup<TKey,TElement>.Grouping
```

But what assembly is it in?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072955/is-it-possible-to-create-some-igrouping-object

Comment: WCF Data Services ServiceOperation? Or WCF operation?

Comment: System.Core has all the LINQ implementations.

Comment: @JeffN825 - I forgot to clarify that.  It is a WCF Data Services  ServiceOperation.  I updated my question.

Comment: System.Core (in System.Core.dll) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx

Comment: That has IGrouping.  But I don't see Grouping (or anything that implements IGrouping) in there.  (Maybe I am just blind?)

Comment: @Vaccano Can you click on it and hit F12 (In VS) to navigate to it's definition?

Comment: @JonC - No that does not work.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Several types in the BCL implement `IGrouping`, however they are all internal and cannot be accessed except by the `IGrouping` interface.

But an `IGrouping` is merely an `IEnumerable<TElement>` with an associated key. You can easily implement an `IGrouping` that is backed by a `List<TElement>` and that should not be hard to serialize across a call boundary:

```
public class Grouping<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement> {

  readonly List<TElement> elements;

  public Grouping(IGrouping<TKey, TElement> grouping) {
    if (grouping == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("grouping");
    Key = grouping.Key;
    elements = grouping.ToList();
  }

  public TKey Key { get; private set; }

  public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator() {
    return this.elements.GetEnumerator();
  }

  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }

}
```

After applying the `GroupBy` operator you can create a list of `Grouping` instances:

```
var listOfGroups =
  source.GroupBy(x => ...).Select(g => new Grouping<TKey, TElement>(g)).ToList();
```

Comment: Probably the easiest approach would be something like: var newGrouping = new List<MyType>().GroupBy(t => t.MyKey);

Comment: @aBetterGamer: I believe that the question is not about how to create an `IGrouping` which is quite easy as you point out but how to recreate "something" that implements `IGrouping` on the other side of a serialization boundary.

Comment: The answer helps me to grasp how `IGrouping<key,value>` can yield multiple values internally +1.

Answer (score 13):

Here is probably the most basic and generic implementation of IGrouping. Its constructor takes a key and a set of values.

```
public class Grouping<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    private readonly TKey key;
    private readonly IEnumerable<TElement> values;

    public Grouping(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> values)
    {
        if (values == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
        this.key = key;
        this.values = values;
    }

    public TKey Key
    {
        get { return key; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> I checked the type with a sample app and it is this:`System.Linq.Lookup<TKey,TElement>.Grouping`.  But what assembly is it in?

It's a type nested in `System.Linq.Lookup<TKey,TElement>`; internal to the `System.Core` assembly.

```
 var groupingType = "1".GroupBy(x => x).Single().GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition();
 Console.WriteLine("Type: " + groupingType);
 Console.WriteLine("Public: " + groupingType.IsPublic);
 Console.WriteLine("Assembly: " + groupingType.Assembly);
```

Output:

```
Type: System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[TKey,TElement]
Public: False
Assembly: System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

---

As of .NET 4.0, there is no public type in the core .NET framework that implements `System.Linq.IGrouping<TKey,TElement>`. If you need such a type (say that's serializable), you'll probably have to roll one yourself, unfortunately.