# How to return "Grouped by" aggregated result?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I trying to understand how to return a group by result in web.api interface, like so...

```
[ActionName("Archive")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetArchiveImport() {
    try {
        var result = _service.QueryFor(x => x.ActionType == ActionType.Import)
            .GroupBy(x => x.InsertDate,
                (key, group) => new {
                    Date = key,
                    Entries = group.ToList()
                }).ToList();

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        _logger.Error("Failed to retrive import file", e);
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
}
```

The `QueryFor` returns => **`IEnumerable<History>`**

I'm not getting any results, can some one explain why?

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: Are you missing a select keyword?

Comment: checked that you have any results without the group by part?

Comment: I do have 390k result set in test. every thing works fine

Comment: what kind of view do you have? if you are sure your testset works perfectly then how did you test that you didn't get any results?

remember that the groupby syntax doesn't return IEnumerable<History>

Answer (score 1):

Why not just simplify to this

```
var result = _service.QueryFor(x => x.ActionType == ActionType.Import)
            .GroupBy(x => x.InsertDate);
```

and check the result with your debug'er. If you don't get any data, then it is your QueryFor that doesn't return any.

Is your question really along these lines [Is there a way to force ASP.NET Web API to return plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11581697/2294065)

You have the data in your result, but doesn't get them over the wire as expected?

If this i supposed to be a normal Web API method your method signature should be like

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, History>> GetArchiveImport()
```

Ok - getting closer :) Web API doesn't know about IGrouping - I guess you can register this somehow.

A quick fix will be to create your own Grouping class, like

```
public class HistoryGroup
{
   public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<History> History { get; set; }
}
```

then change your group by to

```
var result = _service.QueryFor(x => x.ActionType == ActionType.Import)
            .GroupBy(x => x.InsertDate,
                (key, group) => new HistoryGroup() {
                    InsertDate = key,
                    History = group
                })
```

and return `result.ToList()`

the return value for your function would be `IEnumerable<HistoryGroup>`

Comment: Care to comment why this got downvoted, I for one doesn't get the value of (key, group) => new {
                    Date = key,
                    Entries = group.ToList()
                }

Comment: I would like to return the exact result as I've showed, not an other signatures and the same exact grouped data.

Comment: Ok - then you will have to serialize this to xml/json/whatever-you-like yourself.
With the signature above you would just do return result.ToList()

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8508212/2294065 you find more info about the IGrouping problem