# Include Key in IGrouping Serialization

Tags: javascript, c#, json, linq, serialization

I've followed [Martin Liversaege](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98607/martin-liversage)'s answer from this question on Stack Overflow: [What is the implementing class for IGrouping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507561/what-is-the-implementing-class-for-igrouping)

I've implemented my own class that derives from IGroupable as such:

```
public class AjaxResponseGroup<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    readonly List<TElement> elements;

    public AjaxResponseGroup(IGrouping<TKey, TElement> ajaxResponseGroup)
    {
        if (ajaxResponseGroup == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ajaxResponseGrouping");
        }

        Key = ajaxResponseGroup.Key;
        elements = ajaxResponseGroup.ToList();
    }

    public TKey Key { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.elements.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I've got this fun little LINQ statement in my controller:

```
var groupedAuthActions = unitOfWork.AuthActions.GetAll()
    .WhereIf(q != null, x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(q.ToLower()))
    .OrderByDescending(authAction => authAction.CreatedOn)
    .Select(authAction => new AuthActionsListViewModel
    {
        Id = authAction.Id.ToString(),
        Name = authAction.Name,
        Description = authAction.Description,
        Grouping = authAction.Grouping
    })
    .GroupBy(authActions => authActions.Grouping)
    .Select(g => new AjaxResponseGroup<string, AuthActionsListViewModel>(g))
    .ToList();
```

Which is serialized with the following line:

```
string serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groupedAuthActions);
```

However, when that is converted to JSON, the key is not included in the string, instead, the groups are anonymous arrays:

```
[
    [{
        "Id": "5fb20278-2f5e-4341-a02d-070d360066cd",
        "Name": "CreateAuthAction",
        "Description": "Allows the user to create an AuthAction",
        "Grouping": "User Management"
    }, {
        "Id": "1edc56d4-9529-4a18-8684-137d0ccfd4d3",
        "Name": "ReadAuthAction",
        "Description": "Allows the user to view the AuthActions within the system",
        "Grouping": "User Management"
    }],
    [{
        "Id": "f1332b37-44c2-4c86-9cbe-ea3983bf6dfe",
        "Name": "DeleteAuthAction",
        "Description": "Allows the user to delete an AuthAction",
        "Grouping": "Test Group"
    }]
]
```

Other than looking at the `Grouping` property of the first item in the array, how am I to determine what the key of the group is when using the object in the front-end JavaScript?

Is the only/best solution to do something like: (I'd be doing iterative functions, but to illustrate the idea)

```
// myObj = JS Object from return JSON above
var firstGroup = myObj[0][0].Grouping;
```

I feel like there has to be a more elegant and "correct" way of doing things?

Comment: Does [How to serialize/deserialize a custom collection with additional properties using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383736/how-to-serialize-deserialize-a-custom-collection-with-additional-properties-usin) answer your question?  See also [JSON serialize properties on class inheriting list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439335/json-serialize-properties-on-class-inheriting-list/35439861#35439861).

Comment: For anybody else that ends up here. The above comments link contains the answer. Hint [JsonProperty] on public TKey Key.