# How do you add an IGrouping<> 'object' to a list?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, list, collections

So. I've got a list Property that groups values with identical names;

```
List<IGrouping<string, MyItemDTO>> MyList { get; set; }
```

It's initially populated from a database by means of an `IQueryable<>`.

But say I wanted to add a new item to this list using code, how would I go about that? Since IGrouping is an interface, I can't exactly new it up like;

```
IGrouping<string, MyItemDTO> newGroup =  new IGrouping<string, MyItemDTO>();
MyList.Add(newGroup);
```

That doesn't work. I'd like to know, 'what does?' How do I get a new item in there?

Many thanks.

**EDIT:**

A little perspective:

Imagine having two or more cities. These cities have a few respective streets with matching names. `IGrouping<,>` ensures that the street name appears only once in the List. Therefore the data-bound `Combobox` doesn't repeat any values (typically because the end user won't know to what city the street belongs to).

My view has two `Combobox`es. One for street, the other for city. Should a street be selected, the viewmodel will select the corresponding city, unless the street group contains more that one street within it. At that point, the user will be prompted to manually select which city the street resides in.

I figured that `IGrouping<,>` would suit this purpose seeing as it's the default return type when using the GroupBy() extension method. Still open to suggestions though.

Comment: You don't. `IGrouping` is the thing returned by `GroupBy`. It is explicitly not designed to be constructable outside the provider. If you insisted you could of course implement your own `IGrouping` -- but a much saner approach is to convert the `IGrouping`s to something else instead, like a `Dictionary<string, List<..>>`.

Comment: You should probably explain your *original* problem and why you though `IGrouping<,>` would be the solution to it.

Comment: You can use generics to create a new IGrouping instance go to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5073144/7296188)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've updated my description giving a little back story to what led me to do it this way. Perhaps you could have another look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this method to create IGrouping value:

```
IGrouping<string, MyItemDTO> GetIGrouping(string key,MyItemDTO item)
{
    return new[] {item}.GroupBy(val => key).First();
}
```

or if you want several items in group:

```
IGrouping<string, MyItemDTO> GetIGrouping(string key,IEnumerable<MyItemDTO> items)
{
    return items.GroupBy(val => key).First();
}
```

Comment: Note that the result of this, when simply added to a list, can be incorrect if the intent is for the list to contain *unique* groupings (as would normally be returned by `GroupBy` methods). This needs to be taken into account when writing code that operates on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a `GroupBy` call on an `IEnumerable<T>` that produces what you want, or implement `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` as per [this answer to a question about that particular approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8508212/400547).

Answer (score 0):

I think You really do not needed `IGrouping` in your Property , What rather you need is a collection like `Dictionary` , `List` etc.

Still if you want it then here's how you should add items with IGrouping

```
var t = new List<Test>();
foreach (var item in t.GroupBy(x => x.A))
{
  A.MyList.Add(item);
}
```

---

```
public static class A
{
    public static List<IGrouping<string, Test>> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
 public class Test
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }
    }
```

Hope that helps !!

Comment: I've updated the description to shed light on the scenario. Out of curiosity, how would a dictionary be better suited?